# Link to accordion content visible

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Does anyone knows how to create a link to every header (h3) SHOWING his respective content in jquery-ui accordion? from the same and from other pages of the website.

i know i can put a name to tag content but what should i do when the link is in other page? , i been thinking , wouldn't be a problem , i will use link like  mywebsite.com/index.php#nameofthecontent1 ...   but so far i realize isn't possible.  So if i have to put trigger for every content (they are 30 and growing) on different pages sound little silly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @JamesMontagne That is great, stealing that link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can emulate clicking on a section by doing something like:

```
var sectionId = "id-of-the-section-you-want"; // get this from the query string
$('#' + sectionId).click();
```

This should open the section you want. Here's an article on getting the query string values from javascript: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague but are you looking for something like below? I am using a ajax get request to load an external file content into that accordion container. accord3.html is just a sample file I created.You can always use chrome developer tools or firebug to inspect the HTML structure.

```
     $("h3 a").on('click', function(){
            var self = $(this);
            var url = $(this).text();
            $.get(url + ".html", function(data){

                self.parent().next("div").html(data);   
            });

        });
```